# what is the method equivalent to push_back (C++) in java?

Tags: java, c++, methods

> The problem : Longest Increasing Subsequence
>
> // input : int[] a = {3,2,6,4,5,1};

```
vector<vector<int>> l(a.size());

l[0].push_back(a[0]);

for(int i = 1 ; i < a.size() ;i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < i ;++){
        if(a[i] > a[j] && l[i].size() < l[j].size()+1){
             l[i] = l[j];
        }
    }   
    l[i].push_back(a[i]); 
 }
```

- > i want print this output :
- > ```
  >  3
  > ```
- > ```
  >  2 6
  > ```
- > ```
  >  2 4
  > ```
- > ```
  >  2 4 5
  > ```
- > ```
  >  1
  > ```
- > ```
  >  //Thanks so much for Helping
  > ```

Comment: `List.add()`. Goes to show how crazy the C++ method names are. Imagine conflating the notion of pushing onto a stack with the notion of where to push it with the notion of adding to a list.

Comment: It is probably worth looking at the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question in the title line: If you use `java.util.Vector<E>`, then it is `addElement`.  Those would be the closest-match class and method in Java to the C++ template classes that you mentioned in your question.

Docs are here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement-E-

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ArrayList` would be closer considering neither `ArrayList` nor `vector` is thread-safe. The documentation you link to even recommends `ArrayList` if thread-safety isn't needed.

Comment: @chris `ArrayList` is the more conventional choice from a Java programmer's point of view. I was trying to match syntax as close as possible in this case, because that seemed to be what the OP was seeking.